# How do I prevent Kramdown from getting confused by a C++ include?

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

I have written this plugin:

```
module Jekyll
    module Tags
        class Prism < Liquid::Block
            def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
                @arg = text.strip
                super
            end

            def render(context)
                output = super(context)
                "<pre><code class=\"language-#{@arg}\">#{output}</code></pre>"
            end
        end
    end
end 

Liquid::Template.register_tag('prism', Jekyll::Tags::Prism)
```

This is how I use it:

```
{% prism cpp %}
#include <iostream>

// Hello World
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    int a = 10;
}
{% endprism %}
```

Now, the problem is, that I mostly use C++ Code on my website. When I now generate this markdown with Jekyll, then all text after `{% endprism %}` would still be within the `<pre>` Tag, because Kramdown is getting confused by `<iostream>` If I escape it, (`\<iostream\>`), then my plugin works as expected, but my Javascript Highlighter is getting confused.

How can I solve this situation without enabling Jekyll's highlighter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in the CGI Module, that allows for escaping HTML much like htmlspecialchars from PHP. I changed the liquid plugin to this and it works:

```
require 'cgi'

module Jekyll
    module Tags     
        class Prism < Liquid::Block
            def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
                @arg = text.strip
                super
            end

            def render(context)
                output = super(context)
                output = CGI.escapeHTML(output);
                "<pre><code class=\"language-#{@arg}\">#{output}</code></pre>"
            end
        end
    end
end 

Liquid::Template.register_tag('prism', Jekyll::Tags::Prism)
```

It escapes all <> to html special chars. Therefore Kramdown does not get confused and prism.js is still able to highlight the code correctly.

[image: Screenshot of highlighting]

Answer (score 0):

I think your trying to use fenced code block used in [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/).

Why don't you use the [Jekyll code highlighting](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting) works pefectly out of the box for `cpp` ? A base css for highlight is available [here](https://github.com/mojombo/tpw/blob/master/css/syntax.css)

Try :

```
{% highlight cpp %}
#include <iostream>

// Hello World
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    int a = 10;
}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: Because I want to use prism.js. And how does kramdown not get confused when jekyll parses this? It is the same, just a different markdown tag... highlight instead of prism. Also, learning the plugin stuff.